# Binary Converter to Decimal with .NET

Tags: vb.net, binary, converters

I'm started to get the hang of some programming basics but I'm still very new and inexperienced. I am having trouble with a new program I am coding.

I want to have a program in which an 8-bit binary number is put in a textbox, a button is pressed, and the decimal value of the binary number is shown.

Below is the code i have tried:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click

    Dim N As Integer
    N = Convert.ToDouble(tbxBin.Text)
    N = N Mod 2
    N = N \ 2
    lblAns.Text = Convert.ToString(N)

End Sub
End Class
```

Sadly, when I run the program I only get a decimal number of 0 no matter what binary code I put in. I'm very confused because I was told the use Mod class. When I look online for a solution to my problem, I see techniques and various coding processes I've never seen before.

Apparently with my code, I have to repeat what I typed for as many bits as the user is typing in, however, I'm confused as to how I go about that. Do I Dim new variables?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you do any research before posting? http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_binary_to_text.html

Answer (score 2):

Edit: See below for going the other way!! I misread.

Binary to Decimal:

```
Public Function ConvertFromBinary(ByVal input As String) As Integer
    Dim ret As Integer = 0
    Dim splitInput As Char() = input.ToCharArray
    Dim modifier As Integer = 1
    For i As Integer = splitInput.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim thisChar As Integer = Val(splitInput(i))
        If thisChar = 1 Then
            ret += thisChar * modifier
        End If
        modifier *= 2
    Next

    Return ret
End Function
```

...And back again:

Easy answer?

```
Convert.ToString(input, 2)
```

Since that's no fun, however:

```
Public Function ConvertToBinary(ByVal input As Integer) As String

    Dim ret As String = ""

    While input > 0
        ret &= input Mod 2
        input = input \ 2
    End While

    Return StrReverse(ret)
End Function
```

Comment: Didn't the OP want to go from text ("1001100") to a number?

Answer (score 1):

The hard way

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    Dim pwrOf2 As Integer = 0
    Dim ans As Long = 0L
    'first check if the user input a number
    If Long.TryParse(tbxBin.Text, Nothing) Then
        'then look at each char in reverse
        For Each n As Char In tbxBin.Text.Reverse
            Select Case n
                Case Is = "0"c
                Case Is = "1"c
                    ans += 1L << pwrOf2
                Case Else
                    'error - input not in binary, only 1's and 0's 
                    Stop
            End Select
            pwrOf2 += 1
        Next
        lblAns.Text = ans.ToString("n0")
    Else
        'not a number
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

just a suggestion, start by making a function like this:

```
    Public Function Bin_To_Dec(ByVal Bin As String)
        Dim dec As Double = Nothing
        Dim length As Integer = Len(Bin)
        Dim temp As Integer = Nothing
        Dim x As Integer = Nothing

        For x = 1 To length
            temp = Val(Mid(Bin, length, 1))
            length = length - 1
            If temp <> "0" Then
                dec += (2 ^ (x - 1))
            End If
        Next

        Return dec
    End Function
```

then call it with this:

```
txtZ.Text = Bin_To_Dec(txtX.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

first convert to an array of integer then convert that to binary see the code below

```
        public static Byte[] SerializeDecimal(Decimal decimalValue)
    {
        Int32[] arraydDecimalToInt32 = Decimal.GetBits(decimalValue); ;
        Byte[] byteData = new byte[sizeof(Int32) * arraydDecimalToInt32.Length];

        for (Int32 index2 = 0; index2 < arraydDecimalToInt32.Length; index2++)
        {
            Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(arraydDecimalToInt32[index2]), 0, byteData, index2 * sizeof(Int32), sizeof(Int32));
        }
        return byteData;
    }
    public static Decimal DeserializeDecimal(  Byte[] data)
    {
        Int32[] parts = new Int32[4];
        for (Int32 index = 0; index < 4; index++)
        {
            parts[index] = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, index*4);
        }
        bool sign = (parts[3] & 0x80000000) != 0;
        byte scale = (byte)((parts[3] >> 16) & 0x7F);
        return new Decimal(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], sign, scale);
        //See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits(v=vs.110).aspx
    }
```

Comment: That's very strange looking VB.NET ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim binarystring As String
    Dim bitvalue As Integer
    Dim denaryvalue As Integer = 0
    Dim bit As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the binary string")
    binarystring = Console.ReadLine
    Dim lenstring As Integer = Len(binarystring)
    For i = 1 To Len(binarystring)
        bit = Mid(binarystring, i, 1)
        bitvalue = Int(bit)
        denaryvalue = 2 ^ (lenstring - i) * bitvalue + denaryvalue
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(denaryvalue)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```