# Mirror the Bits of an Integer

Tags: vb.net, bit

How do I mirror the bits of an integer of unknown length in VB.Net?

By mirroring I mean putting the first bit last and so on.

i.E.:

10010100  mirrors to
00101001

The functions construct would be:

```
Public Function ReveseIntegerBitwise(ByVal initialInteger As Integer)
    Dim reversedInteger As Integer

    ' Do Something with initialInteger and put it in reversedInteger

    Return reversedInteger
End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean with "unknown length"? An Integer has certain length. The "built-in" Integer in .NET has 32 bits or 4 bytes ALWAYS. Another thing are the Int16, Int32 or Int64 from C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary Converter to Decimal with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250855/binary-converter-to-decimal-with-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
Function Foo (value as Integer) as String
     Return new String(Array.Reverse(Convert.ToString(value,2).ToCharArray()))
End Function
```

and it returns a string with the reversed bits.

Comment: hm...If I enter in this function 148 (10010100) it returns a string with "00101001". If I enter 8 (1000) it returns "0001"...I think that's what he wants...

Comment: `Array.Reverse` is not a function, so it doesn't return a value and so that code won't compile with Option Strict On. You could use `Return New String((Convert.ToString(value, 2).Reverse().ToArray()))`.

Comment: The OP wants to return an `Integer` from the function, so you should convert it _back_ to one as well.

Comment: @VisualVincent But how to get the leading zeros on an integer?

Comment: @AndrewMorton : My comment was mainly directed to Gomez, but I imagine that the binary number that the OP wrote was just an example, since based on his function he wants to return the reversed bits as an Integer. You can write as many leading zeros as you like, it doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: unless you want to preserve the leading zeros in case you want to mirror it again - in which case returning an integer wont work properly